# Ndk-stack-trace tool not working on Windows

Tags: android, android-ndk, stack-trace

I have a problem with executing the NDK stack trace tool on Windows.
Probably jus a pretty stupid mistake, so here is what I try:

```
...\android-ndk-r8d\ndk-stack.exe -sym ".../JNITest/obj/local/x86/" -dump ".../crash.txt"
```

The message I get is the following:

```
********** Crash dump: **********
...

Stack frame #00  eip: 30303030: Unable to open symbol file .../JNITest/obj/local/x86//☺. Error (123): Unknown error
```

So there is an .so file in this folder that should contain symbols (BTW: how can I check if that is the case?)

Comment: Does this `☺` represent a name of the file, or this actually the name that `ndk-stack` was looking for? Could it be that the log file you provided to `ndk-stack` has wrong unicode markers or a non-utf8 encoding?

Comment: The log file is UTF-8, i think this is more a problem of the Windows Terminal not displaying the UTF-8 output of the programm correctly

Comment: could you paste the relevant piece of the log?

Comment: @AlexCohn do you mean the crash log from JNI?

Comment: yes, the crash log from JNI

Answer (score 1):

When you build the native library with ndk-build, it creates an `.so` file with all debug information, usually in the directory `<proj>/obj/local/armeabi`, and after that *installs* this file into `<proj>/lib/armeabi` by stripping off the debug symbols. The latter is packed into the APK.

**armeabi** above is used most often because most Android devices out there use ARM CPU. Your post refers to **x86** subdirectory. Did you really use an Intel-powered device for this project? Did you build your native library for x86? If you did, can you find this file in your `<proj>\obj\local\x86` directory?

Comment: Yes, I did it for x86 because I tested it on the x86 emulator. And there is an .so file in that folder, along with subfolders with all the .o files

Answer (score 0):

I had the same crash of ndk-stack.exe when using Android NDK Release 9, 64-bit on Windows 7. Updated to a newer NDK version, Release 9c, 64-bit, and the problem is gone. Apparently a bug in earlier releases of NDK.

Greg

Comment: Thanks for the info, I will have a look at that once I am working on an NDK project again